# Look for phrase in string, and also look for wildcards after the phrase

Tags: php, strpos

I'm looking for a way to display some code based on the URL of the site.

Case 1:

If url contains `getting-started` do something

Case 2:

If url contains `getting-started/*` (could be anything) show something else.

I'm currently getting the URL string as:

```
$url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
```

And then performing `strpos`

```
if (strpos($slug,'getting-started')){
```

But I need something to specifically target URLs where the end is `getting-started` and also be able to identify when there is more that comes after it.

Answer (score 0):

You should use regex:

```
(getting-started)$ // gets the phrase at the end of the string
(getting-started)(.*) // gets the phrase + anything else
```

You could combine this with [`preg_match()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php)